# Как правильно конвертировать строку даты и времени в формат датывремени?

Tags: python

Данные даты и времени берутся из датасета, где они записаны в следующим образом:

```
(datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 3, 11, 0, 3, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0), 'UTC')),)
(datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 3, 11, 0, 15, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0), 'UTC')),)
(datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 3, 11, 0, 16, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0), 'UTC')),)
```

Не могу понять, как их преобразовать к формату датывремени?

Приведенные пример - это выборка одной строки из столбца датасета, если смотреть на тип данных, то это будет str.

```
print(my_df['datetime'][0])
print(type(my_df['datetime'][0]))

(datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 3, 11, 0, 3, 
tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0), 'UTC')),)
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Они и так в формате datetime

Comment: не надо type. `df.info()` что говорит?

Comment: @strawdog говрорит что это object

Comment: Тогда воспроизводимый пример датасета в студию. можно на файлообменник.

Comment: @strawdog вот пример из 3 строчек
(datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 3, 11, 0, 3, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0), 'UTC')),)
(datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 3, 11, 0, 15, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0), 'UTC')),)
(datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 3, 11, 0, 16, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0), 'UTC')),)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, данные формата datetime хранятся у вас в csv как есть, то есть, при прочтении в датафрейм они получаются в строковом формате.

В таком случае предлагаю сделать так:

```
dates = pd.DataFrame(df['datetime'].str.extractall('(\d+)').unstack().values[:,:-1].astype(int), columns=["year", "month", "day", "hour", "minute", "second"])
df["new_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(dates)
df = df.drop("datetime", axis=1)
```

теперь ваш df:

```
         new_datetime
0 2021-11-03 11:00:03
1 2021-11-03 11:00:15
2 2021-11-03 11:00:16
```

ну и тип данных:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------        --------------  -----         
 0   new_datetime  3 non-null      datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Сложно понять, что вы подразумеваете, но сейчас это тип данных `tuple`. Обратиться к нему можно по индексу. То есть я создам переменную, куда положу ваши данные и поиграюсь

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> a = (datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 3, 11, 0, 3, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0), 'UTC')),)
>>> type(a) # спросим какой тип данных у переменной а
<class 'tuple'>
>>> type(a[0]) # здесь обращение по индексу к нулевому члену кортежа
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> a[0].isoformat() # здесь говорю, что нулевую запись кортежа пробразовать в формат ISO
'2021-11-03T11:00:03+00:00'
```

Comment: Это тип данных str.

Comment: @ДанилаСоловьев может быть, что асболютно не очевидно из вашего вопроса. Может дополните его входными данным и их типом?

Comment: @ДанилаСоловьев Вижу, добавили, но очень очень странно, нельзя так сохранять данные в любом случае. Откуда эти данные? Можно написать костыль, который будет отлавливать данные из строки, но это не корректно, на мой взгляд.

Comment: это данные полученные в результате парсинга большого количества аксес логов. И они были сохранены в датасет формата csv